# How do I use printf to output values of spherical coordinates converted to cartesian coordinates in C?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, printf

I am writing a program in C where part of the program is supposed to convert spherical coordinates into cartesian and then display them on the screen, but I always get a compilation error for this part.  I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong,   or if I am missing something.  Any suggestions? I think the problem is with how I am using printf, such as using the wrong parameters or wrong number of parameters.  The error is:

```
Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0prog.c: In function 'print_test':
prog.c:21:9: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printf'
  printf(cartesian.x);
         ^
```

Here is the part of the code that I think I am doing wrong based on the error message (I think I added some stuff to the code, but the effect should remain the same for the most part):

```
void print_test (struct threedCartesianData cartesian)
{
    printf(cartesian.x, cartesian.y)
}
```

I am pretty sure I am using printf wrong, but not sure how exactly.

Comment: "as far as I can tell going by tutorials, it should be right." Do throw away such useless tutorials!

Comment: At least show the error..Update: anyway I see one at least: missing semicolon in `print_test`

Comment: You are missing "format" parameter for `printf`. If you want to print two floating point numbers you would use `printf("%f %f", x, y);` instead of `printf(x,y)`. Format parameter tells what the latter parameters are in order to print them properly. Link to reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: That's not how `printf` works...

Comment: Please explain how it is off topic.  Even before the edits, although bad, I thought the question was on topic (for the most part anyway, maybe a little less emphasis on the math aspect).

Comment: I reworked my question to make it more relevant and understandable (I think).  Please review when you can.

Comment: Oh.  Wait lol.  I see now why this question is bad.  Thing is though, typos weren't the full reason, it was also due to improper useage of printf (missing format parameter).  That wouldn't apply to that reason for being bad.

Comment: Ok, cut it down to the part that I though was giving a problem.  Usually people get mad at me for not putting enough information about the code, not when I put too much.

Comment: @cluemein People don't like too much code because it *usually* is an indicator of little-to-no research (essentially copy & pasting the program to SO as soon as you get an error). Being able to boil the question down to a few lines of code that can be quickly reproduced by users not only makes it easier for people to test their solution and provide a good answer, it also shows that you've spent time trying to debug the problem and have found the smallest amount of code to reproduce it. Your current version the post is much better than it was before, I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the info.  Also will now be using a new system of reviewing my prospective questions before I post them.

Comment: Apparently though, there is something still wrong with my question as it got downvoted again after you upvoted or voted to reopen it again.

Comment: Should I change the text of the question to deempathize the math part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a format string to `printf()`
- Add a semicolon after `printf()`
- Declare `cart` and delete unused `cartesian` in `ConvertSpclToCart()`
- Change `ConvertSphclToCart` to `ConvertSpclToCart` in `main()`
- Change `int main()` to `int main(void)`

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159


struct threedSphericalData
{
    float azimuth;
    float inclination;
    float range;
};

struct threedCartesianData
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

void print_test (struct threedCartesianData cartesian)
{
    printf("%f %f\n", cartesian.x, cartesian.y);
}

struct threedCartesianData ConvertSpclToCart(struct threedSphericalData spherical)
{
    struct threedCartesianData cart;
    cart.x = spherical.range * cos(spherical.inclination * PI/180)*cos(-(spherical.azimuth)*PI/180);
    cart.y = spherical.range * cos(spherical.inclination * PI/180)*sin(-(spherical.azimuth)*PI/180);
    return cart;

}


int main (void)
{
    struct threedSphericalData spherical;
    spherical.azimuth = 35;
    spherical.inclination = 10;
    spherical.range = 300;
    struct threedCartesianData cartesian = ConvertSpclToCart(spherical);
    print_test(cartesian);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still gives me the same error. It also says invalid initializer at ConvertSpchToCart 3rd to last line.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is that for some reason itt isn't registering the change of the function name.

Comment: This solution worked once I made sure all the old data from previous compiles was cleared from memory.

Comment: Don't know why that was an issue to begin with though (the memory issue).